# Mmenu bug when "Smart cache to CSS" is active in Prestashop

Tags: android, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, mmenu

For some reason, my pages keep jumping to the bottom of the page for users on android devices. This bug only appear when i activate "Smart cache to CSS" in Prestashop. I know its because of the mmenu, as it quickly opens before the page scrolls down to the footer. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? 
My version is 1.6.1.14 btw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <title>jQuery.mmenu playground</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Include jQuery.mmenu .css files -->
  <link type="text/css" href="path/to/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Include jQuery and the jQuery.mmenu .js files -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/jquery.mmenu.all.js"></script>

  <!-- Fire the plugin onDocumentReady -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#menu").mmenu({
           "extensions": [
              "pagedim-black",
              "theme-dark"
           ],
           "navbars": [
              {
                 "position": "top"
              }
           ]
        });
     });
  </script>
```

```
  <!-- The page -->
  <div class="page">
     <div class="header">
        <a href="#menu"></a>
        Demo
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <p><strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
           Click the menu icon to open the menu.</p>
     </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The menu -->
  <nav id="menu">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, here it is

Comment: Could you paste your store URL or a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: Sure its bomo.dk